# Audio is not defined when using nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

using this code keeps giving me the error `ReferenceError: Audio is not defined`. which I get because nextjs is ssr but there should be a way to make it work either way

```
  const musicPlayers = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>(
    new Audio("")
  );
```

I found online that I could use this thing

```
  const musicPlayers = useRef<false |HTMLAudioElement>(
    typeof Audio !== "undefined" && new Audio("")
  );
```

but then I need to use a false as possible option which gives me and error on the play pause code

```
Property 'paused' does not exist on type 'false | HTMLAudioElement'
Property 'play' does not exist on type 'false | HTMLAudioElement'.
     if (musicPlayers.current?.paused) {
          musicPlayers.current.play();
        } else {
          musicPlayers.current?.pause();
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```js
const musicPlayers = useRef<HTMLAudioElement | undefined>(
  typeof Audio !== "undefined" ? new Audio("") : undefined
);
```

Then you can call:

```js
musicPlayers.current?.play();
musicPlayers.current?.pause();
```

Comment: ReferenceError: HTMLAudioElement is not defined :/